# Simple JS Question about date ( fullyear + 1)

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to add a number new date in javascript

How ever the number is coming in from a json file.

Here is what i have.

```js
myObj = {"yearsleft":"2", "name": "john"};

var term = myObj.yearsleft;
var d = new Date();

var year = d.getFullYear() + term.toString();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = ''+ (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + year;
alert(output);
```

above is a working example

However its just appending 2 to the end of the year. which isnt what i want it to do.
I want it to add onto 2019
if that's possible.

Comment: term is string convert to number and add var year = d.getFullYear() + parseInt(term.toString());

Comment: You mean in the original json file?
Because its impossible for me to change that. as its not something i can change.

Comment: Not on the json file. Just the convert `term` variable to number :)

Comment: @Eddie thank you your link helped me lots.

Comment: You can't add values to date parts without testing if the result is a valid date. E.g. 29 Feb 2004 + 2 years is 29 Feb 2006, but that's an invalid date because 2006 wasn't a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding string to a number, convert it to int and then add.

```
var year = d.getFullYear() + parseInt(term.toString(), 10);
```

Comment: Be careful, [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) does NOT default to base 10... so always use `parseInt(..., 10)`

Comment: @freefaller—[yes it does](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix), unless the string starts with `'0x'`, when it defaults to base 16. P.S. MDN is just a public wiki that anyone can contribute to, it is not normative. ECMA-262 is.

Comment: @RobG - fair enough, it must have changed over the years, because it used to default to base-8 if you weren't careful

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a number - currently you're concatenating not adding.

```js
myObj = {"yearsleft":"2", "name": "john"};

var term = myObj.yearsleft;
var d = new Date();

var year = d.getFullYear() + +term;
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = ''+ (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + year;
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d.getFullYear() + parseFloat(term);
```

Seem to have fixed it for me.

Comment: it makes more sense to use parseInt instead of Float, so use `parseInt(term, 10)` the 10 is for the base, like @freefaller said on a different answer, parseInt doesn't always default to base 10, so you should add it just in case.